# How to re-render the same component on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-lifecycle

Well I am making this weather app with the use of an api. So, first I have to show the weather of a default city. Then when I select the other cities, the component will render again to give me the weather data of selected cities.
So far I have done on my project:

```
const initialDivisionId = "3";

const getDivision = (divisionId) => {
  return divisions.find((division) => division.id === divisionId);
};

class Weather extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const division = getDivision(initialDivisionId);
    this.state = {
      divisionId: initialDivisionId,
      lat: division.lat,
      long: division.long,
      currentWeatherData: [],
      hourlyWeatherData: [],
      dailyWeatherData: []
    };
  }

  onDivisionChange = (event) => {
    const divisionId = event.target.value;
    const { lat, long } = getDivision(divisionId);

    this.setState({
      divisionId: event.target.value,
      lat: lat.lat,
      long: long.long
    });
    
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${this.state.lat}&lon=${this.state.long}&units=metric&exclude=alerts&appid={api_key}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            currentWeatherData: result.current,
            hourlyWeatherData: result.hourly[0],
            dailyWeatherData: result.daily[0]
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.setState({
            error
          });
        }
      );
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.currentWeatherData);
    console.log(this.state.hourlyWeatherData);
    console.log(this.state.dailyWeatherData);
    return (
      <div>
        <Title />

        <Select
          variant="filled"
          w="30%"
          placeholder="Select option"
          value={this.state.divisionId}
          onChange={this.onDivisionChange}
        >
          {divisions.map((division) => (
            <option key={division.id} value={division.id}>
              {division.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Select>
        <div>
          <Stack spacing={6}>
            <Heading color="tomato" size="4xl">
              {this.state.currentWeatherData.dt}
            </Heading>

            <Heading color="gray" size="3xl">
              {this.state.currentWeatherData.temp}
            </Heading>

            <Heading color="blue" size="2xl">
              {this.state.hourlyWeatherData.pressure}
            </Heading>

            <Heading color="black" size="xl">
              {this.state.hourlyWeatherData.temp}
            </Heading>

            <Heading color="black" size="lg">
              {this.state.dailyWeatherData.clouds}
            </Heading>

            <Heading color="yellow" size="md">
              {this.state.dailyWeatherData.humidity}
            </Heading>
          </Stack>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Title = () => {
  return (
    <Text align="center">
      <Heading size="xl">Weather App</Heading>
    </Text>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Weather />
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So, I know I have to use shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method if I want to re-render. How can I re-render the same component if I want to have the weather response of other cities? Or do I need to pass states as props to other component and then I have to fetch the api? Need help!

Comment: If you set state, the component should re-render without you having to do anything else to it. Have you tried just setting state with the new city info?

Comment: what does that mean? whenever there will be change in state your component will re-render..

Comment: Every time you call `this.setState` the component will re-render, if a DOM change should take place according to the data which was changed.

Comment: Ah I see your issue, you have your API call only in `componentDidMount`, so it'll only fetch data when your component mounts. What you'll want to do is also have it in `componentDidUpdate`. To try to avoid redundant code, you can put it in its own method.

Comment: @Nick okay so the fetch should be inside the componentDidmount?

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're hitting isn't that you need to re-render your component, it's that you need to hit the weather API when your state updates. You can do this by making sure you call your API in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. Here is some updated code that does that (and abstracts the API call to avoid redundant code).

```js
fetchWeatherData() {
  fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${this.state.lat}&lon=${this.state.long}&units=metric&exclude=alerts&appid={api_key}`
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState({
          currentWeatherData: result.current,
          hourlyWeatherData: result.hourly[0],
          dailyWeatherData: result.daily[0]
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({
          error
        });
      }
    );
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchWeatherData();
}

componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
  if (prevState.lat !== this.state.lat || prevState.long !== this.state.long) {
    this.fetchWeatherData();
  }
}
```

In the constructor, make sure to bind `fetchWeatherData` to `this`.

```js
constructor(props) {
  // Existing constructor code here
  this.fetchWeatherData = this.fetchWeatherData.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: it throws a ```Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined```.

Comment: You might have to do some troubleshooting inside the return of the fetch call. That error tells me there's either no `result.hourly` or `result.daily` in the return from your fetch call at some point. Is there a different type of return from the API if, for example, you provide it a bad lat/lon?

Comment: (Also make sure the API key is included correctly. Right now I copied it how you had it in the question, but it looks like it should be a template literal variable `${api_key}` instead of what it currently is (without the dollar sign)

Comment: I obviously entered the right api key. But I think there might be some issues with the response when I select the option. Have to work on that.

Comment: Your code here makes an infinite loop, took my friend to notice it.

Comment: Check out the docs here, you can use the second argument of componentDidUpdate to check it either lat or long are different than before. Otherwise, don’t fetch the data. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: @tanjimanim updated my answer to _only_ fetch if `this.state.lat` is different than `prevState.lat` or `this.state.long` is different than `prevState.long`